# Automating SAML login for service users?

Tags: authentication, saml

Is it possible to fully automate the login of a service user (i.e. a programmatic, software based "user") without user interaction?

I have a service provider that's SAML protected. Basic Auth and OAuth are not allowed. The IdP is PingIdentity. The client is a piece of Java code that wants to perform some activity in the SP - normally the client is a human.

In the normal flow of events, a human user/client would access the SP and be redirected to the IdP, they'd *manually* enter their username/password, upon success they'd be redirected to the SP to complete their action.

In my situation the client is some Java code, not a human. Is there *ANY* way to automate the login from the service user (Java client) that allows the code to follow the SAML redirects and provide username/password to the IdP like a human would and complete the login process? Any pointers to open source libs or examples are gratefully accepted. I cannot find any references to this process after several days of searching.

Comment: [OpenSAML](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OS30/Home) is your friend.

Comment: This is a programming question, which is answerable with a google search